# Regex for word characters in any language

Tags: php, regex

Testing the PHP regex engine, I see that it considers only `[0-9A-Za-z_]` to be word characters. Letters of non-ASCII languages, such as Hebrew, are not matched as word characters with `[\w]`. Are there any PHP or Perl regex escape sequences which will match a letter in any language? I could add ranges for each alphabet that I expect to be used, but users will always surprise us with unexpected languages!

Note that this is not for security filtering but rather for tokenizing a text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `[\pL_]` - see the reference at

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I also had to add the `u` modifier to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try `\p{L}`. It matches any kind of letter from any language. If you don't want to use char set `[]`.