# RegEx match all word characters, with umlauts from different languages

Tags: regex, perl

I want to check if a person's name is valid.
It should check latin letters, also with umlauts (i.e. öäüÖÄÜé).

unfortunately nothing i've tried works.

regarding many sources (following some links),

https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

[Regex for word characters in any language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626208/regex-for-word-characters-in-any-language)

`\p{L}` should work, but it doesn't works for me.
Do i have to `use` a library for this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = "testString";
print $1 if ($test =~ m/^(\p{L}+)$/);   #testString
$test = "testStringö";
print $1 if ($test =~ m/^(\p{L}+)$/);   #no print msg
$test = "testéString";
print $1 if ($test =~ m/^(\p{L}+)$/);   #no print msg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Perl that the source code of your file is in utf8. Add

```
use utf8;
```

After

```
use strict;
```

Comment: Additionally, in real code the string will probably come from outside the source code, so you will likely need to decode it from UTF-8 either after reading or using a `:encoding(UTF-8)` layer when reading.