# SAS: Regex for word characters in any language

Tags: regex, sas

Suppose you have twitter data available.

E.g. there is the following tweet:

> RT @Mydy_Rabycad: (English in comments) TRACK #1 Mantra, neboli
>   posvátné slovo, které je třeba si opakovat a nezapomínat. Ať se děje
>   cokoli…

Cleaning it for further processing with

```
clean_text = prxchange("s/[^\w#@]/ /",-1,text);
```

> RT @Mydy_Rabycad English in comments TRACK #1 Mantra neboli posv tn
>   slovo kter je t eba si opakovat a nezapom nat A se d je cokoli

As you see, one is losing a lot of valuable word-characters.
What I would like to get is:

> RT @Mydy_Rabycad English in comments TRACK #1 Mantra neboli posvátné slovo které je třeba si opakovat a nezapomínat Ať se děje cokoli

Generally, I would like to remove all extra-characters that are not part of any words in any language, such as punctuation, smilies etc... the goal is to tokenize some random twitter data.

So the example code (that doesn't work) would be

```
data have;
infile datalines4 delimiter='\\\\\';
length text $200.;
input text $;
datalines4;
RT @Mydy_Rabycad: (English in comments) TRACK #1 Mantra, neboli posvátné slovo, které je třeba si opakovat a nezapomínat. Ať se děje cokoli…
;;;;
run;

data have2;
set have;
clean_text = prxchange("s/[^\w#@]/ /",-1,text);
/*Remove multiple blanks introduced through the above regex*/
clean_text = prxchange("s/\s+/ /",-1,clean_text);
run;
```

So is there a control sequence in SAS (9.4 T1M6) like \w for the English language, i.e. something like \p{L} that allows to subset every alphanumeric wordletter in every language?

As suggested in the comments, the following Regex do not work either

```
prxchange("s/(u?)[^\w#@]/ /",-1,text);
prxchange("s/[^\p{L}#@]/ /",-1,text);
```

Also the compress function does not yield the desired results with the 'ka' modifier.

```
compress(text,' ','ka');
```

The question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626208/regex-for-word-characters-in-any-language) but with regard to SAS.

Comment: Not sure but perhaps use unicode `(?u)[^\w#@]` https://regex101.com/r/jBK5tS/1

Comment: What about compress with 'ka' modifier?

Comment: Does `"s/[^\p{L}0-9#@]/ /"` work?

Comment: @johannesBleher can you please edit your post to include your desired output so we can help effectively and not guess what you want.

Comment: i will, sorry. i am currently afk.

Comment: @Schilker. I have now updated the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, no that doesn't work. I think it's the SAS implementation of Regex...

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your suggestion does not work either. I think it's the regex implementation in SAS...

Comment: @Reeza also `compress(text,' ','ka')` does not work.

Comment: Not possible in some languages . is an letter while in most it is punctioation. That could also be possible for other Characters.

Comment: @Lee: Do you have an example for a language where . is a letter? I can't find any... I can update the question to only include European languages  as discussed [here](https://nordendivision.nfi.ku.dk/about_ungegn/romanization/Leira%20Vigleik%20_2008_%20Alphabets%20Letters%20and%20Diacritics%20in%20European%20Languages.pdf). 

Interestingly, in Python my initial idea with `\w` works perfectly, according to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jBK5tS/2)

Comment: I only know Lojban that uses it https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lojban/Sounds_and_alphabet Note that Lojban is constructed language so it is used rarely. But the is no gurantie that is not used by another language. Also some languages have currently no writting system so there might be a change that they cause trouble also.

Comment: Lojban and Fula(which is spoken in africa for example gambia) use apostrophe (') as character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LONG VERSION:

Just keep adding the special characters you want to keep to the string in `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_@#áéříťě"`. Cheers!

```
 Data want; 
    set have;
      New_text=compress(text,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_@#áéříťě","kis");
 run;
     /* 'k' keeps the characters in the list instead of removing them.
        'i'  ignores the case of the characters to be kept or removed.
        's' adds space characters (blank, horizontal tab, vertical tab, carriage return, line feed, and form feed) to the list of characters.*/
```

SHORT VERSION:

This will remove any character you add to/replace in `"():."`

```
Data want; 
   set have;
     New_text=compress(text,"():.","i");
 run;
```

Comment: In the absence of a regex original answer. I will accept this brute force non-regex as correct. Thanks for your answer!